# Why can't you pass data constructors around like regular functions in OCaml?

Tags: function, ocaml

For instance, consider the following code:

```
type foo = Foo of int

let apply z f = f z

(* This is not allowed *)
let create_foo = Foo

(* This is allowed *)
let create_foo i = Foo i

(* This is not allowed *)
apply 1 Foo

(* This is allowed *)
apply 1 create_foo
```

Are data constructors special function that must be fully applied?
When used as a function, `Foo` and `create_foo` are identical in what they do. What's the reasoning for disallowing the usage of `Foo` as a regular function that you can pass around and partially apply?

Haskell seems to allow this behaviour.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the horse's mouth, Xavier Leroy, in [this mailing list message from 2001](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/ml-archives/caml-list/2001/08/47db53a4b42529708647c9e81183598b.en.html):

> The old Caml V3.1 implementation treated constructors as functions like SML.
> In Caml Light, I chose to drop this equivalence for several reasons:
>
> - Simplicity of the compiler.  Internally, constructors are not
>   functions, and a special case is needed to transform Succ into
>   (fun x -> Succ x) when needed.  This isn't hard, but remember that
>   Caml Light was really a minimal, stripped-down version of Caml.
> - Constructors in Caml Light and OCaml really have an arity, e.g.
>   C of int * int is really a constructor with two integer arguments,
>   not a constructor taking one argument that is a pair.  Hence, there
>   would be two ways to map the constructor C to a function:
>   fun (x,y) -> C(x,y)
>   or
>   fun x y -> C(x,y)
>   The former is more natural if you come from an SML background
>   (where constructors have 0 or 1 argument), but the latter fits better
>   the Caml Light / OCaml execution model, which favors curried
>   functions.  By not treating constructors like functions, we avoid
>   having to choose...
> - Code clarity.  While using a constructor as a function is sometimes
>   convenient, I would argue it is often hard to read.  Writing
>   "fun x -> Succ x" is more verbose, but easier to read, I think.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that makes sense. Adding a little [historical context](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caml#History) to this answer (since I had to search this up).


"[Caml's] successor, Caml Light, was implemented in C by Xavier Leroy and Damien Doligez, and the original was nicknamed "Heavy Caml" because of its higher memory and CPU requirements. Caml Special Light was a further complete rewrite that added a powerful module system to the core language. It was augmented with an object layer to become Objective Caml, eventually renamed OCaml."

Answer (score 3):

I won’t speak in the name of the language designers. However, constructors have stronger properties than general functions. They

1. are injective,
2. have a fixed arity,
3. do not execute arbitrary code,
4. and allocate a memory block (except in some optimized cases).

So it makes sense to distinguish them syntactically.

Point 2 means that you can apply them totally, without building nor calling any closure. In a way you are inlining the constructor, seen as a function, but point 3 and 4 say that the code of the function is straightforward (it simply allocates and initializes a value block). In fact, there is no need for a function in memory that represents the constructor.

Thus, by forcing constructor applications to be total, you can have a faster compilation scheme, that also better evidences allocations when reading your OCaml code. This is appreciated by some, as allocations are among the prime things monitored by performance-concerned OCaml programmers.

The syntax `Constr (a,b,c)` resembles that of regular tuples `(a,b,c)` on purpose: it does mostly the same thing, only with a different type (and with the tag of the constructor, different from the implied tag of tuples). In this example the constructor does *not* take one tuple argument, but rather it takes *three* arguments `a`, `b` and `c` where parentheses and commas are part of the syntax of the constructor. So the syntax token `Constr` cannot be treated as `(fun abc -> Cons abc)`. In other words, uncurried syntax does not lead naturally to a syntax for partial application (including no-application), which is on purpose.

The tuple syntax in patterns also evidences better injectivity, I think. In pattern-matching, you are actually destructing a tuple, you are not magically finding the unique values for the arguments of an injective function such that the application of said function yields the matched value. But that is more minor.

That said, conflating constructors and functions is perfectly reasonable too. Coq does it, even though its syntax draws on Caml. OCaml constructors not behaving as proper functions is a recurring subject of complaint, for example, you may skim the discussion of [this pull request](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/pull/9005).